# Find $\lim_{x\to 1^+}\left\lfloor\sqrt\frac{1-\sqrt{x-1}}{1+\sqrt{x-1}}\right\rfloor$

Tags: limits

Find the  limit:

$$\lim_{x\to 1^+}\left\lfloor\sqrt\frac{1-\sqrt{x-1}}{1+\sqrt{x-1}}\right\rfloor$$

where $\lfloor x\rfloor$ is the floor function.

Generally :

How can
\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to a^-}f(x)&=\lim_{x\to a}g(x) \\
\lim_{x\to a^+}f(x)&=\lim_{x\to a}g(x)?
\end{align}

Comment: Hint: If the limit exists, it must be because the function value is _constant_ in some interval $(1,1+\varepsilon)$.

Comment: Start simplifying the function inside the floor function, by example multiply denominator and numerator by $1-\sqrt{x-1}$. Probably it will help you remember that the floor function can be divided in a set of constant functions.

Comment: At $x=1$, the value is clearly $1$. However, approaching from the left will give you a complex number, and approaching from the right will give you $0$

Comment: Following @HenningMakholm.  Replace $x$ by $1+\epsilon^2$ and look at what happens for $\epsilon\to 0^+$...

Comment: Can't understand your "Generally" question.

Answer (score 2):

Using these two approximation $\sqrt{1-\varepsilon_1}\approx1-\dfrac12\varepsilon_1$ and
$\dfrac{1+\varepsilon_1}{1+\varepsilon_2}\approx1+\varepsilon_1-\varepsilon_2$‎ where $\varepsilon_1$ and $\varepsilon_2$ are small numbers we see
for $x=1+\varepsilon^2$ that
$$\lim_{x\to 1^+}\left\lfloor\sqrt\frac{1-\sqrt{x-1}}{1+\sqrt{x-1}}\right\rfloor=
\lim_{x\to 1^+}\left\lfloor\sqrt\frac{1-\varepsilon}{1+\varepsilon}\right\rfloor=
\lim_{x\to 1^+}\left\lfloor\sqrt{1-2\varepsilon}\right\rfloor=
\lim_{x\to 1^+}\left\lfloor1-\varepsilon\right\rfloor=0
$$

Answer (score 2):

For $x\in(1,2)$, we have

$$0<1-\sqrt{x-1}<1$$ and $$1+\sqrt{x-1}>1$$

so that the ratio is in $[0,1)$ and the floor of its square root is $0$.